# Downloading Ubuntu to acer chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook c720. I would like to install Ubuntu on it but do not want to use crouton, as it is not real Ubuntu. I am aware there are other posts on the subject, but they are all different and very old. I don't know which tutorial is correct.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: @user68186: close vote retracted as per your more funded comment then mine!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a HP Chromebook 14 and im running Ubuntu using crouton and it works perfectly fine.

For ChrUbuntu Simply just follow the steps. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/764181-how-to-install-linux-on-an-acer-c720-chromebook

Comment: I've used crouton before, but It is not true native Ubuntu.

Comment: Yea, I know. Link above is for ChrUbuntu not Crouton. Just making sure you understand. :P

Comment: When I have that completed, how do i switch between Ubuntu and chrome OS?

Comment: @Gman Smith When you reboot CTRL + L will boot into ChrUbuntu and CTRL + D will boot into Chrome OS

Comment: You should make a better differentiation between crouton (chroot) and ChrUbuntu (native) in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install one of HugeGreenBug's modded for Acer C720 
[here.](https://www.distroshare.com/distros/category/16/)

In my experience crouton has been sluggish and glitchy